# report builder 3.0 cascading parameter for bool

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder3.0

I am building a report in SSRS 2008 R2 Report Builder 3.0. In this report i have a Parameter named @CustomerID, a list of Customers in a dropdown. I then have a number of Bool Parameters eg. @UseFirstName and @UseLastName which are based on settings for each. The population of @UseFirstName and @UseLastName work fine for the first customer i choose but when i choose a new customer the values are not updated.
Obviously the population the first time is working against the dataset but after that it stops getting updated when i choose customer in the dropdown. Any ideas?

i have set "always update" on all my parameters.

Code for getting the parameter data:

```
SELECT * FROM pen.CustomerReportSettings
WHERE (CustomerID = @CustomerID)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the bool parameter radio group will work the way you want it. The only thing I can think of that will get you close is to force the bool parameters to a text datatype and set the default values to "Get values from a query" with the value field being the field related to the parameter. You also need to specify the Available Values as "Get values from query" to force the parameter to reload when the @CustomerID changes. This should yield a drop down box with one selectable option and the value of the dropdown set to that option.

Comment: this would work but i still need the user to be able to pick from True or False if they want to. I simply convinced the employer to just manually pick for each report. Since there are only a few parameters it's OK. Thank you for your answer. I will mark it as correct because it does solve the issue i posted.